# DragDrop registration did not succeed exception

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I launch a dialog from out of proc COM server, the dialog has some drag drop ctrl operations within it. After some research found that the dialog has to be launched in  STA thread. I managed to do that but there were several side effects on subsequent dialogues. So, planned to implement Dragdrop operation without using the inbuilt one. ie. By handling mouse events and switching cursors, weather this is feasible.?

Comment: There's a world of hurt in out-of-process servers showing UI.  A window like that has no relationship at all with your own windows.  Big reason why Adobe software sucks so much.  But drag+drop between windows owned by different processes is rarely a problem.  Why you want to hack that is not clear.

Comment: my drag+drop is within the window. (I guess)Because the dialog is displayed from OutofProc server the thread displaying the dialog is in MTA that leads to the exception http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/5928/jferror.png  I dont wanted to introduce a separate STA thread to show the dialog - thats why thought to try implement custom Drag drop with mouse events.

Comment: Yes HansPassant - as you said there is a world of hurt in out-of-process server showing UI.  am struggling now(unfortunately we had to follow it to enable our 32Bit Addin for 64 Bit office)..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it is not possible to implement custom drag drop after setting AllowDrop property to false. Reason: While dragging from one control - mouse events for other controls are not fired. ie,. with in a form, while dragging 1 button to another panel : even mouse over/mouse move of the form /target panel dint get fired.